# Vue2: prop set and updates dynamically but template does not?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am new to Vue. I am still learning and the S.O. Community has really accelerated that.

I started making more complex components after figuring out some core basics, and some more advanced things (e.g. propagating data from children through multiple nested components, which can not be done with v-model).

I have now encountered a bug. It occurs in 2 instances, but I do not understand why. The Vue inspector shows the data being updated dynamically. The template and / or the computed value just does not update and I can not figure out why.

I spent two hours trying to prune this to a smaller MWE, but I can not reproduce the bug without less complexity (I think it has to do with Vue not liking components that depend on data being passed through more than 1 component).

** M.W.E. **

As there are a few of components, I am providing the MWE via Code Sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/mqoy658v9x

where one can see that it is a fairly simple table

[image]

**Description of Components**

- DataTable: the main component for rendering the table
- DataTableCaptionSort: shows a list of how data is sorted
- DataTableCell: a cell in the table
- DataTableFilter: the filter...
- DataTableHeader: component mapping over fields
- DataTableHeaderCell: a header cell - should show icon next to it if sorted
- DataTableRow: component mapping over fields for each record

The DataTable component expects an Object which resembles a database, i.e. each key is an identifier for a record, and the value thereof is a record.
Each record is an object where the keys are fields of the data.

** The Bug **

The bug - as stated in the title - is that two of the above mentioned components have data which is being dynamically changed correctly, but the templates or computed values are not.

The problem components are DataTableHeaderCell and DataTableCaptionSort.
As one can see, clicking on a header toggles the sort (via a cycle of ascending, descending, not sorted). Depending on the sorted value, the header cell should show either an uparrow or down arrow. Likewise the caption should be a list showing the timsort order, e.g. x (up) y (down)

Neither do.

Can someone please help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried usig watcher on the variables to update changes on the DOM?

Comment: @SanketDhoble I have tried adding a watcher to log when the prop changes, but it does not log, despite the vue inspector showing me that the prop has changed